# Apparmor DENIED Mysql

Tags: mysql, mint

Salve pessoal.

Estou enfrentando um pequeno problema com meu MYSQL no Linux Mint.
Quando tento inicializar o serviço, o APPARMOR me nega a permissão, segue os logs:

```
Ago 28 09:07:42 Comerlatto-NTB systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Ago 28 09:07:42 Comerlatto-NTB systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A unidade mysql.service concluiu o desligamento
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- A unidade mysql.service concluiu o desligamento.
Ago 28 09:07:42 Comerlatto-NTB systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unidade mysql.service sendo iniciado
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- A unidade mysql.service está sendo iniciada.
Ago 28 09:07:42 Comerlatto-NTB audit[31015]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/31015/status" pid=31015 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=122 ouid=122
Ago 28 09:07:42 Comerlatto-NTB audit[31015]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=31015 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=122 ouid=0
Ago 28 09:07:42 Comerlatto-NTB audit[31015]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/31015/status" pid=31015 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=122 ouid=122
Ago 28 09:07:42 Comerlatto-NTB kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1503922062.148:231): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/31015/status" pid=31015 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=122 ouid=122
Ago 28 09:07:42 Comerlatto-NTB kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1503922062.148:232): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=31015 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=122 ouid=0
Ago 28 09:07:42 Comerlatto-NTB kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1503922062.148:233): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/31015/status" pid=31015 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=122 ouid=122
Ago 28 09:07:42 Comerlatto-NTB systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

---

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Seg 2017-08-28 09:10:14 BRT; 15s ago
  Process: 31784 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 31777 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 31784 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 31785 (mysql-systemd-s)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 344.0K
      CPU: 245ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─31785 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─31849 sleep 1

Ago 28 09:10:14 Comerlatto-NTB systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Ago 28 09:10:14 Comerlatto-NTB systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

---

Alguém saberia o que pode ser? Na minha visão leiga o APPARMOR está negando acesso de leitura, já procurei em vários fóruns e nenhuma solução me ajudou.

Comment: Resolveu? Tô passando por isso. abraço.

Comment: Eu reinstalei o MySQL

Answer (score 1):

A orientação geral indicada para resolver este problema está em alterar a permissão de carga do apparmour.

Observe a mensagem que indica qual recurso teve falta de permissão e qual a permissão requisitada:

Ago 28 09:07:42 Comerlatto-NTB audit[31015]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" **name="/proc/31015/status"** pid=31015 comm="mysqld" **requested_mask="r"** denied_mask="r" fsuid=122 ouid=122

Edite o arquivo

> /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld

e inclua as permissões necessárias, no caso:

```
/proc/* r,
/sys/devices/system/node/* r
```

Reinicie seu serviço:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, na época em que me ocorreu este problema eu segui estas mesmas orientações, reiniciei o mysql, como também a máquina, porém não resolveu. O problema persistiu até o momento em que eu reinstalei o MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Opa! Beleza Pessoal? 
Estava buscando uma solução para este mesmo problema e notei uma coisa interessante, no meu caso eu notei uma mensagem de erro que indicava falta de espaço em disco na saída do comando `journaul -xe`. Aumentei o espaço em disco do servidor e resolveu.

Segue a saída do comando:

```
Nov 21 08:38:01 ip-192-168-231-20 rsyslogd[880]: action 'action 3' (module 'builtin:omfile') message lost, could not be processed. Check for additional error messa
Nov 21 08:38:01 ip-192-168-231-20 rsyslogd[880]: file '7' write error: No space left on device [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
```

Eu havia tentado essas mesmas alternativas citadas acima e não resolveram, o problema no meu caso foi espaço em  disco. Espero poder ajudar!